# C copies into two buffers though just one should be filled

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, buffer-overflow

I wrote some code in C which should `strcpy` some input data to a declared buffer. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *args) {
  char buff_1[12];
  char buff_2[3] = "ABC";

  strcpy(buff_1, args);
  printf("buff_1: %s \n", buff_1);
  printf("buff_2: %s \n", buff_2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Input: ");

  if(argc > 1)
    function(argv[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

If I now run the binary I would assume that everything more than 11 input arguments would result in a buffer-overflow, But In fact it appends my Input to both buffers:

```
./main (perl -e 'print "A"x15')
buff_1: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
buff_2 :ABCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Also checking the variables using the gdb shows that my input arguments are stored in both buffers:

```
(gdb) x/1s buff_1
0xffffd284: 'A' <repeats 11 times>
(gdb) x/1s buff_2
0xffffd281: "ABC", 'A' <repeats 11 times>
```

I compiled the code using the following command:`gcc -m32 -O0 -g -fno-stack-protector -o main main.c` using `gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)`

Can someone explain how that ist possible?

Comment: What, exactly, do you think the result of a buffer overflow *ought* to be?

Comment: If you print out the addresses of the variables (with `%p`), you'll see that they magically align next to each other, so "ABC" (w/o the missing zero at the end) will follow with buff_2's contents.

Comment: Or just don't count at all, `char buff_2[] = "ABC";`. And enable compiler warnings.

Comment: I don't really get all the downvotes. I was just sticking with some code I found in the book about buffer-overflows I'm currently reading. The main goal of this code is to result in a buffer-overflow in later steps as well as analyzing the assembly code. I thought asking a question on a knowledge platform would result in useful comments and answers such as the one below. Getting hated for asking a question is not really motivating.

Comment: My compiler throws an error on this line: `char buff_2[3] = "ABC";`: _'ABC' : array bounds overflow_

Comment: Apparently GCC is crappy at warning for this particular bug. Likely because some C standard-fetishist coded this part, there's a subtle flaw in the C standard 6.7.9/14: "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
terminating null character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
elements of the array." This nonsense exception applies only to string literal initializers, but not to regular array initializers.

Comment: I believe all other compilers on the market except GCC would warn for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough space for null termination for `buff_2`. So `printf("buff_2: %s \n", buff_2);` will overflow your buffer, resulting in *undefined behaviour*.

```
char buff_2[3] = "ABC"; // Not enough space for \0 
char buff_2[4] = "ABC"; // OK
char buff_2[] = "ABC";  // OK, Size will be 4
```

Comment: My compiler throws an error on this line: `char buff_2[3] = "ABC";`: _'ABC' : array bounds overflow_

Answer (score 3):

Writing more characters to a buffer than what there is space invokes undefined behavior. There is no predictable outcome; you can't assume anything when you do this. You can't expect to always get a deterministic run-time error.

This is why you need to check the size of the argument before passing it to `strcpy`. Failing to do so is a bug.

As a side note, you have a bug here: `char buff_2[3] = "ABC";`. There is not enough room for the null termination. Meaning you'll invoke undefined behavior when you try to print that array, because it is not a valid, null-terminated C string.